# Using an index with multiple OR statements

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get this query to use an index.

```
explain SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM products WHERE (stock_disabled = 1 OR negative_stock_allowed = 1 OR stock > 0)
```

This is what it returns:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  p   ALL     multi_index     NULL    NULL    NULL    2890    Using where
```

The multi_index is an that contains stock_disabled, negative_stock_allowed and stock in the same order. I think the index is not working because of the multiple OR statements. What can I do here?

Comment: Have you tried creating 3 separate indexes? One on each column and then run the explain?

Comment: MySQL can only use one index per query so it wouldn't do me any good.

Comment: just check with single condition stock_disabled=1 and share if index is using here...

Comment: OR Is a kiiler even with index so you may use UNION to have each condition separately

Answer (score 0):

"USE INDEX foo" if you explicitly want to use an index

```
SELECT * FROM products USE INDEX(`multi_index`)
```